# Bootstrap pull-left and pull-right are not responding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML look like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail news-listing">
        <div>
        <img class="img-responsive fr-draggable" src="/CustomContents/DSC03804.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="">Test Article</h4>

            <p class="">
        </p><p>Test News</p><p></p>
            <p></p> 
            <div class="btn-block">
                <div class="pull-left">

                    <a href="/News/Test-Article" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left" role="button">More Info</a>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">

                    <a style="cursor:pointer" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>18/11/2016</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I would like two links in the bottom to respond going one under another if there is not enough space, but instead they look like this. what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why you don't play with the grid system?

Comment: Because I wanted buttons to be in the left and right corners as far as possible from one another.

Comment: The combined width of the two elements is higher than your view-port width, so you can't put them side-by-side. You will have to make them shorter (lower the padding/font).

Comment: `pull-left` and `pull-right` work as expected. When the screen is too narrow they will eventually wrap.. even when using floats.

Answer (score 0):

Either use bootstraps grid, so you can set two columns OR change the order of the elements so that the `pull-right` one is before the `pull-left` one in the source.

```
<div class="thumbnail news-listing">
    <div><img class="img-responsive fr-draggable" src="/CustomContents/DSC03804.JPG" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="">Test Article</h4>
        <p class="">&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Test News</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="btn-block">
            <div class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="cursor: pointer;">18/11/2016</a></div>
            <div class="pull-left"><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-left" href="/News/Test-Article">More Info</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If its not working then TRY as below,

```
<div style='float:left'>
```

instead `<div class='pull-left'>` and

```
<div class='float:right'>
```

instead `<div class='pull-right'>` corrosponding

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of using bootstrap! Plus, the `pull-left` class simply floats to the left...!

Comment: I know that pull-left = float: left

Comment: Then what is the point of swapping out the classes for inline styles that do exactly the same...?!?

Comment: Remove class='btn-block' from your code & then perform

Comment: May be btn-block Is responsible for that problem